# How to allow users to delete data from Google play games?

Tags: google-play-games

I am currently working on a game with Google play games integration. So far everything works fine. Users can log in, achievements and leaderboards are updated. I also implemented snapshots.
In the game I want to give the user the possibility to delete all his data. With snapshots this works well but I can not find a way to remove the user data from  achievements and leaderboards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing unpublished games, you can [manage the leaderboard data](https://developers.google.com/games/services/management/api/scores) and perform various operations such as clear / reset leaderboards.

When you are live, you can [hide a user](https://developers.google.com/games/services/management/api/players/hide) so they do not appear in public leaderboards. This will not hide the player from their own leaderboards though.

Comment: I tried the Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect function. This did disconnect my account and also cleard the authorization but it did not clear my state in the leaderboard or my achievements.

Comment: Removing revocation from response for now, see if revoking and then waiting (e.g. 24h) has an effect, some mechanisms can take time to clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can't unfortunately. Or at least a year ago, when I checked that, it was not possible. I doubt this has changed since.